# 6.6.23_Add on & Pose Mode arent showing up in viewport?

Tags: add-on, pose-mode

ive used 3 red boxes to show what im talking about in the attached image.
https://i.ibb.co/0yYhVxq/2023-06-06-14h15-59.jpg

I downloaded and enable auto rig pro, but it isnt showing up in the "n" hotkey tool bar any ideas?

Also when clicking on an object> I cant find Pose mode anymore whats going on?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: That's a pretty old Blender version that you're using (3.1.2). Are you sure that the addon version is compatible with that Blender version?

Comment: For your second question, Why would you expect to see Pose mode when you just have default cube in your scene?

Comment: @JohnEason
hey i noticed it was for 2.9.3 haha, thanks for that
Edit) After trying it in 2.9.3 its still not showing up on the toolbar.. yeah im stumped

Comment: You'll need to ask that question on the addon's web site in that case. This Q&A site only helps with problems using Blender and its built-in addons. Questions about third-party addons are off-topic here.